# Complex Path Integral over $e^{1/z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\gamma\colon [0,2\pi]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C},\ t\mapsto e^{it}$ be a path. I wanted to compute $\int_\gamma e^{1/z}\mathrm{d}z$ by using the series form of the exponential function.

So put $\int_\gamma e^{1/z}\mathrm{d}z=\int_\gamma \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=0}^n 1/(j!z^j)\mathrm{d}z$. Because, the series converges uniformly and the integral is additive, I can write
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n\int_\gamma 1/(j!z^j)\mathrm{d}z$

Then substituting the path yields: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n\int_0^{2\pi} i/j! e^{-it(j-1)}\mathrm{d}t$ and all terms are zero except at $j=1$ which gives $2\pi i $ for the whole integral.

I have not learned the residual theorem or cauchy integral yet, so I can not give a more compact answer on how to integrate. Can somebody confirm my answer (hopefully much faster) by using more advanced theorems?

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that your second line should have an $n$ as the upper limit on your sum (or get rid of the limit. Either works). The rest seems fine

Comment: Note that by the residue theorem, we just need the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Laurent Expansion at zero and multiply that by $2\pi i$. Since the coefficient is one (easily seen by the series you have in your post), we just get $1 \cdot 2\pi i = 2 \pi i$